# Qual a diferença entre o operador "in" e o método "hasOwnProperty" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, característica-linguagem, objetos

Um comportamento inesperado (pelo menos pra mim), ocorreu com os seguintes trecho de código que irei demonstrar abaixo:

```js
const str = new String('olá SOpt');

console.log('Usando "in"', 'length' in str); // true
console.log('Usando "hasOwnProperty"', str.hasOwnProperty('length')); // true
```

Repare que até aqui, nada de novo, funcionou como esperado, mas o código abaixo me fez ficar com dúvidas:

```js
const str = 'olá SOpt';

console.log('Usando "hasOwnProperty"', str.hasOwnProperty('length'));
console.log('Usando "in"', 'length' in str); // vai lançar um erro
```

Se rodar o código acima, o segundo `console.log` vai ter um erro dizendo algo como:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in olá SOpt

Foi ai que as dúvidas surgiram...eu esperava que fosse funcionar normalmente o uso do `in` porque uma *string* tem uma propriedade `length`

```js
const str = 'olá SOpt';

console.log('Usando "hasOwnProperty"', str.hasOwnProperty('length'));
console.log('lenght: ', str.length); // 8
```

Só que usando `'length' in str` retornou um erro. Obviamente, minha linha de raciocínio em achar que `in` e `hasOwnProperty` eram a mesma coisa, só uma forma *"enxuta"* de escrever, falhara:

```js
const str = new String('olá SOpt');

console.log('Usando "in"', 'length' in str);
console.log('Usando "hasOwnProperty"', str.hasOwnProperty('length'));

const str2 = 'olá SOpt';

console.log('Usando "hasOwnProperty"', str2.hasOwnProperty('length'));

try {
  console.log('Usando "in"', 'length' in str2); // ocorre um erro
} catch (error) {
  console.log(
    `Erro ao usar o "in" em: console.log('Usando "in"', 'length' in str2);`,
  );
}
```

### Perguntas

- Qual a diferença entre o operador `in` e o método `hasOwnProperty`?
- Quando usar um ou outro?
- Por que o `in` em *string* declarada usando `new String('foo')` funciona, mas não funciona com `'foo'`?

---

Só por curiosidade, tentei usar em estrutura do `Map`, mas pelo visto, somente `.has()` funciona para o mesmo:

```js
let map = new Map();

map.set('name', 'Cardeal');

console.log('name' in map);              // false
console.log(map.hasOwnProperty('name')); // false
console.log(map.has('name'));            // true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Qual a diferença entre o operador `in` e o método `hasOwnProperty`? Quando usar um ou outro?

#### Operador `in`

O operador `in` pode ser utilizado em **objetos** para verificar a existência de alguma propriedade. O `in` percorre toda a cadeia de protótipos até encontrar a propriedade, retornando `falso` do contrário.

O operador `in` verifica existência de qualquer tipo de propriedade, o que inclui propriedades cuja chave é um *symbol* e propriedades não enumeráveis.

Utilize-o quando você quiser verificar se determinado objeto possui uma propriedade, própria ou herdada via cadeia de protótipos.

#### Método `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` e função `Object.hasOwn`

Já o método `hasOwnProperty` é definido no protótipo do construtor `Object`. Desse modo, quase todo valor do JavaScript possui esse método uma vez que quase todos os objetos nativos da linguagem estendem, prototipicamente, `Object.prototype`.

O `hasOwnProperty` funciona de modo similar ao `in`. No entanto, não percorre a cadeia de protótipos. Somente as propriedades do "próprio objeto" (do inglês, *own property*) são varridas para a verificação.

Utilize `hasOwnProperty` quando você quiser verificar se o objeto em questão possui determinada propriedade, desconsiderando herdadas prototipicamente.

A função `Object.hasOwn`, introduzida recentemente na linguagem, tem o mesmo comportamento semântico se comparado ao método `hasOwnProperty`. Se o ambiente suportar, **é preferível utilizar `Object.hasOwn`** pelos motivos [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#description) explicitados.*

---

#### O operador `in` só trabalha com objetos

O erro mencionado na pergunta, tal como:

> ```
> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [...]
> ```

Ocorre tendo em vista que o operador `in` funciona somente em **objetos**. Quando você tenta aplicá-lo diretamente em um primitivo (tal como `string`, `number`, `symbol` etc), o erro em questão será lançado, já que os valores não se tratam de um objeto, mas sim de um valor primitivo.

Por isso que:

```
let strObject = new String('oi');
let strPrimitive = 'oi';

console.log('length' in strObject); // -> true    Não lança erro.
console.log('length' in strPrimitive); // Error   Lança erro.
```

Ao utilizar `new String`, ocorre a instanciação de um novo objeto string. Portanto, `in` funcionará (já que fora aplicado em um objeto). Contudo, ao tentar aplicar `in` em `strPrimitive` (que foi atribuída ao valor avaliado pela literal `'oi'`, que é um primitivo string), o erro é lançado.

Da [especificação](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-relational-operators) da linguagem:

```
RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression

  Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
  Let lval be ? GetValue(lref).
  Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
  Let rval be ? GetValue(rref).
  If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
  Return ? HasProperty(rval, ? ToPropertyKey(lval)).
```

Repare que o algoritmo explicitamente lança um erro no caso do segundo operando de `in` não for do [tipo](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values) [objeto](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-object-type).

Vale salientar que o operador `in` ainda pode performar as chamadas *private brand checks*, que não são possíveis com `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` ou `Object.hasOwn`. Contudo, isso vai além do escopo desta resposta. Ver mais sobre isso [aqui](https://v8.dev/features/private-brand-checks) e [aqui](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields-in-in).

---

#### Notas e observações finais

1. Vale observar que primitivos (como string) podem ter acesso aos métodos do respectivo construtor por um mecanismo do JavaScript chamado "*primitive wrapping*". Isso significa que, internamente, trata-se de um primitivo, mas que encontra-se "envolvido" por um objeto, o que permite acesso aos métodos (como o próprio `hasOwnProperty`, que advém da herança prototípica). Por algum motivo a linguagem foi feita para considerar o acesso a propriedades de primitivos algo factível, mas não permite aplicá-los ao `in`. É confuso, mas é a linguagem. Que aceitemos.
   Mais detalhes nestas [outras respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A69296%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20%22primitive%20wrapping%22).
2. Em relação ao `Map`, tanto `in` quanto `hasOwnProperty` não podem ser utilizados para verificar existência de um valor pela chave no mapa tendo em vista que o funcionamento do `Map` é diferente de um "objeto normal". Os valores do `Map` não são armazenados como se fossem meras propriedades de um objeto, isto é, os valores do mapa não são exatamente "propriedades". Portanto, a existência desses valores não pode ser testada por `hasOwnProperty` ou `in`, que trabalham com **propriedades**.