# Como verificar se objeto possui propriedade específica sem o operador "in"?

Tags: javascript, objetos, propriedade

Alguns navegadores não suportam o [`inputMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode), como o Safari. Então, para então mitigar a situação, eu iria ter um outro comportamento se o `inputMode` existisse ou não.

Pesquisando achei o operador `in`:

```js
if ("inputMode" in document.querySelector("input")) {
  console.log("Existe inputMode no <input>")
}
```

```html
<input>
```

**Isso funciona.** O problema é que, uma vez que estou usando outra linguagem, não tenho como chamar o operador `in` (bem até teria como, mas seria um trabalho significativamente maior apenas para isso).

---

**Existe alguma **função** que faça o mesmo do que o `in`?**

Como posso ter o mesmo comportamento do `in` sem utilizar este operador em especifico? Utilizando alguma função (que não seja `eval`, obviamente).

Comment: Só não entendi muito bem porque não dá para usar o `in`. Poderia explicar um pouco melhor? Fiquei curioso.

Comment: Estou usando Golang, e compilando para WebAssembly. Então o `querySelector` se torna: `js.Global().Get("document").Call("querySelector", "input")`.  Eu só tenho acesso ao `.Call`, `.Invoke` e `.InstanceOf` (...), mas não tem nenhum `.In`. Então, não deduzo que não há como usar o `in`. As funções que tenho acesso [são essas](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Bool). O "método mais difícil" seria criar um CallImport para chamar a minha função em JS dentro do Golang, [algo como isso daqui](https://tinyurl.com/33c3hmhf). _Eu omiti essa informação, porque tornaria tudo mais confuso._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar a função [`Reflect.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/has), que tem o mesmo funcionamento do operador `in`, só que em formato de função qualificada no objeto global `Reflect`.

Então:

```
if (Reflect.has(document.querySelector("input"), "inputMode")) {
  console.log(1);
}
```

Vale lembrar que o operador `in` (e portanto `Reflect.has`) são diferentes de `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`. [Saiba mais nesta outra resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/502733/69296)